# How to include column headings to result dataset but only if the query returns rows?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Need to add headings to stored procedure's result dataset but only if the query returns rows.

Tried adding column headings to the resulting dataset using a union but I only want the column headings to exist if other rows are returned from query.

If no other records, I need the result to be a zero byte file (no headings).

declare @myValue as int = 999

```
select 
   'Column One'
  ,'Column Two'

union all

select cast([Col1] as varchar)
      ,cast([Col2] as varchar)

FROM [dbo].[myTable]
where [Col1] = @myValue
and  @@RowCount > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a common table expression for your query, so you don't have to repeat it:

```
with cte(c1, c2) as
(
    select cast([Col1] as varchar) 
          ,cast([Col2] as varchar) 
    from [dbo].[myTable]
    where [Col1] = @myValue
)

select c1, c2
from
(
    select c1, c2, 2 as c3
    from cte
    union all
    select 'Column One' 
          ,'Column Two'
          , 1 
where exists
    (
        select 1 
        from cte
    )
) order by c3
```

Comment: Without an outermost `ORDER BY` there's not guarantee about the sort order. The *headers* might appear anywhere...

Comment: Now this looks, as if your headers will appear as footers ;-) Btw: I'd use `ROW_NUMBER()` for the set to enforce some sorting (if needed) and `0` for the "headers"...

Answer (score 0):

Add same FROM clause and TOP 1 to your "dummy columns names" part. If there are no records it will return nothing, if there are records it will return one row.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
       'Column One',
       'Column Two',
       1 AS SortOrder 
FROM [dbo].[myTable]
WHERE [Col1] = @myValue
AND @@RowCount > 0

UNION ALL

SELECT cast([Col1] AS varchar),
       cast([Col2] AS varchar),
       2 AS SortOrder 
FROM [dbo].[myTable]
WHERE [Col1] = @myValue
AND @@RowCount > 0
ORDER BY SortOrder
```

Comment: Without an outermost `ORDER BY` there's not guarantee about the sort order. The *headers* might appear anywhere...